# Changing the value of a previously declared variable that is also an element of an Array?

Tags: java

so I have tried searching for the answer to this question, but really don't know exactly how to find my answer.  I am trying to insert values into an array, whose elements i declared previously in the same class.  It does not work as far as I can tell.  The element will change, but not the original variable the element represents.  Is this because they are not the same variable (the array makes a copy or something?  I hope this makes sense, but if not here is some sample code:

```
public class bucky {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    tuna tunaObject = new tuna();
    tunaObject.assignArray(25);
}
}
```

.

```
public class tuna {
int day;
int month;
int year;

int dateArray[] = {day, month, year};

void assignArray(int dayInput){
    dateArray[0] = dayInput;
    System.out.println(dateArray[0]);
    System.out.println(day);
 }
}
```

The output is:
25
0

So clearly day does not get altered.  Though I wish it would, and wonder how I can make this work.

Unfortunately it's late.  I've been working at this for hours.  I'm tired.  And I'm pretty sure the clocks just rolled back an hour on me....  Knowing the answer to why this doesn't work would make it all worth while. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`int` is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), not a [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx), so `day` and `dateArray` does not store references to the values but the actual values.

If you want to assign the new value to `day` as well, you must do that explicitly:

```
void assignArray(int dayInput){
    dateArray[0] = dayInput;
    day = dayInput;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`day` is the instance variable of class `Tuna`, and your array is of type int which just uses date (an int variable) at its first index.so, your dateArray is simply using the value of day at its first index.

```
   int day=12;

    int dateArray[] = {day};
```

now the first index value of dateArray would be 12.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your dateArray you affect values by copying values of date, month and year. Those are not references.
So do not expect to change your attributes by modifying the array values.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly new to Java (as I can tell from your lack of use of Java conventions), and you should know that this pointer stuff doesn't happen in Java for this particular case of yours.

Primitive types (integers in your case) aren't passed by reference, they are passed by value.

The solution to your problem is to just add another line

```
day = dateInput
dateArray[0] = day
```

every time you update the value of day.